# Best practice for populating constant map used in reusable method Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using a reusable method to map two codes, when we receive 'a' we want to use '01' in our code. This is a static method so is it right that it only gets created once and we reuse the method or is this bad practice and it is unnecessarily processing every time we call this method? this good practice or should I be creating this map somewhere else and just using the method for returning the values from it?

```
    private static String mapStatus(String duckStatus){

       
        Map<String, String> statusMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        statusMap.put("a","01");
        statusMap.put("b","02");
        statusMap.put("c","03");

        if (!statusMap.containsKey(duckStatus)){
            throw new NullPointerException("Invalid Code does not map to status code");
        }
        return statusMap.get(duckStatus);
    }
```

Comment: Probably up for debate, but `public enum DuckStatus{}` might be a good choice for the constant conversion?  Unless those values actually come from somewhere dynamic.

Comment: Interesting yea now that you say it an enum probably would make more sense

Comment: If the values are constant, and you want to store things like `DuckStatus status;` and use either of the values.  Again, you're example didn't really explain HOW it was being used, just what you needed hence the "up for debate"

Comment: So there is 2 different applications that use different codes for status, they are both constants, when one app makes a call to this app we want to map the codes from app 1 to be used here.

Comment: Do both apps share the code for converting status'?  I'd still probably do it, to give each status a name and two possible values.  Each app can determine which of the two values they need to parse/send.

Comment: Only the 2nd app needs to map the codes. I was planning on giving the values constant values instead of values in the map for readability. But thinking enum might be more efficient?

Comment: Leave a sample enum for the use case as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, `enum` can be a good choice but again as already mentioned by @kendavidson it is debatable. From the performance angle I don't see much of a difference between `enum` and `HashMap` here but in my opinion `HashMap` will be more appropriate and will provide better readability. Only difference I suggest in the code you have written is, make the `HashMap` statically populated so that `HashMap` build up time is avoided every time you want to lookup the `statusMap` whenever the call is made to `mapStatus` method. The modified code will look like below:

```
public class Test {
    private static final Map<String, String> STATUS_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        // Mapping the status values in Duck Creek to the Values used here
        STATUS_MAP.put("a", "01");
        STATUS_MAP.put("b", "02");
        STATUS_MAP.put("c", "03");
    }

    private static String mapStatus(String duckStatus) {
        if (!STATUS_MAP.containsKey(duckStatus)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid code " + duckStatus + " does not map to status code");
        }
        return STATUS_MAP.get(duckStatus);
    }
}
```

Note:

1. Not sure if you wanted to check for `duckStatus` in
   `duckCreekToEDMStatusMapper` or `STATUS_MAP`, I am using `STATUS_MAP`
2. Instead of `NullPointerException` better to use
   `IllegalArgumentException` as it is appropriate here.

Comment: Yea was meant to use status map that was a copy and paste issue, was refactoring question for stack overflow to not use my actual variable names and forgot to change that one. Great answer exactly what I was looking for!